# Proof that the sets $(-m,m)$ for $m \in N$ form an open cover of R with no finite subcover

Tags: general-topology

Sorry guys, I am still learning how to use Latex correctly.
I think I can prove that there is no finite sub-cover with the Archimedean property, but I am not sure how to prove that an infinite unions of sets is an open cover of the real numbers. For the finite subcover part

Let $S=\cup \{(-k,k)\}$ for $k$ from $1$ to $n$. Let $M=\max(S)$. By the archimedean property, there exist a real number larger than $M$, thus there is no finite sub cover.

Comment: are you asking how to prove that $\mathbb{R}=\cup_{k\in \mathbb{N}}(-k,k)$?

Comment: yes, I am. Sorry about that.
The question has two parts. First prove that R=∪k∈N(−k,k)

and second prove that there is no finite sub cover of R using an union of sets (-k,k)

Comment: Name your favorite real number. Round it up. Convince yourself that your number is in one of the open intervals.

Comment: No need to be sorry. Think about a given $x\in \mathbb{R}$. Does it belong to some of the open sets you are considering?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an outline of a proof.

Suppose that the result were false and some $y \in \mathbb{R}$ were not in the union.  Then either $y$ or $-y$ is a positive number not in the union.  Let $x$ be the greatest lower bound of the set of positive numbers not in the union.

Prove that $x-1$ is positive and in some $(-k, k)$.  Prove that a neighborhood of $x$ is in $(-k-2, k+2)$ and therefore $x is not the least upper bound.  This is a contradiction, so the result must be true.